# Solving a system of coupled differential equations

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration

I have no experience and am new to Mathematica, trying to solve and plot phase difference vs time using these equations.(http://salt.uaa.alaska.edu/physics_public/metro.pdf)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPeQt.png

This is my NDSolve code, which is just outputing error messages.

`s = NDSolve[{x''[T]+Sin[x[T]]+0.01x'[T][-1+3.3x[T]^2]-0.011Cos[x[T]]D[Sin[x[T]] + Sin[y[T]], {T, 2}]==0, y''[T]+Sin[y[T]]+0.01y'[T][-1+3.3y[T]^2]-0.011Cos[y[T]]D[Sin[x[T]] + Sin[y[T]], {T, 2}]==0,x[0]==0,y[0]==0,x''[0]=0},{x,y},{T,50}]`

As I have no idea about what I'm doing wrong, is this a problem with formatting, numerical values, or something else entirely?

Any help with solving this will be very much appreciated!

Comment: Do not use square brackets for grouping of terms. Use ( ) instead. Also, since you have 2 second order odes, you need 4 initial conditions. The correct ones. The i.c. should be of order less than the ode order. You have y''(0)=0 as Ic. This is wrong in syntax and logic also.

Comment: You can look at help for many examples.

Comment: Are you attempting to solve a single specific equation from that nine page paper? Can you tell me which one it is? Where did your constants come from? I don't see the same constants in the paper. It might help for you to try to imagine you are someone who doesn't know anything about what you have spent many hours trying to figure out. If you were that person then what description could help you get up to speed and be able to provide the kind of help that is desired without having to spend all the time that you have spent to get where you are now. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 3):

Needed corrections:
(1)  Don't use brackets to group expressions use parentheses, (2) Use a space for multiplication so don't use 0.1x but rather 0.1 x, (3)  Since second order DE, need x[0], x'[0], y[0] and y'[0], (4)  When assigning init conditions use double equal signs as in x[0]==1, (5)  I added some random init conditions to run it.

Also, I used NDSolveValue as more convenient and `ParametricPlot` since I think you wish a phase plot

```
{xSol, ySol} = 
 NDSolveValue[{Sin[x[T]] + (x^\[Prime]\[Prime])[T] - 
     0.011 Cos[
       x[T]] (-Sin[x[T]] Derivative[1][x][T]^2 - 
        Sin[y[T]] Derivative[1][y][T]^2 + 
        Cos[x[T]] (x^\[Prime]\[Prime])[T] + 
        Cos[y[T]] (y^\[Prime]\[Prime])[T]) + 
     0.01  Derivative[1][x][T] (-1 + 3.3 x[T]^2) == 0, 
   Sin[y[T]] + (y^\[Prime]\[Prime])[T] - 
     0.011  Cos[
       y[T]] (-Sin[x[T]] Derivative[1][x][T]^2 - 
        Sin[y[T]] Derivative[1][y][T]^2 + 
        Cos[x[T]] (x^\[Prime]\[Prime])[T] + 
        Cos[y[T]] (y^\[Prime]\[Prime])[T]) + 
     0.01  Derivative[1][y][T] (-1 + 3.3 y[T]^2) == 0, x[0] == 0, 
   y[0] == 0, Derivative[1][x][0] == 1, 
   Derivative[1][y][0] == 1.5}, {x, y}, {T, 0, 50}]
ParametricPlot[{xSol[t], ySol[t]}, {t, 0, 50}]
```

[image]